# Spring Data JPA Annotations for Many-to-Many Table Relationship

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a web application using Spring Boot. I have database tables as follows:

```
role
----
id  name
1   admin
2   user
3   employee

employee
--------
id  name
1   Juan
2   Pedro
3   Marcos
4   Lucas

user
----
id  employee_id role_id     username    password
1   1           1           juan1       hello
2   1           3           juan2       hello
3   2           2           pedro1      hello
4   2           3           pedro2      hello
5   3           3           marcos      hello
6   4           3           lucas       hello
```

And the following are the domain object classes:

```
public class Role  {
...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

---
public class Employee {
...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

I'm wondering what annotations I needed to use in the **User** class. I'm following this [tutorial](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/). But this does not have third class since the third table (**book_publisher**) does not have fields other than the foreign keys (**book_id**, **publisher_id**).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a to many association from Employee to User because User is a so called attributed association with attributes.

The User entity will have a composite ID as primary key.

Please find an excellent article about that topic from Thorben Jansen:
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/many-relationships-additional-properties/

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'll look into it.

Comment: @JulezJupiter If my answer is helpful I would highly appreciate if you up-vote it and/or mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just found out my reference site has also post similar to the link you've given: https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-extra-columns-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/